# How to check child if it is exist in firebase list using angularfire2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I need to check if  firebase list exist using angularfire2.

This is my parent list:

[image]

I need to check if the child **Messages** is exist.

This is my code :

```
  checkChild(){
    let usersRef = this.db.list(`/Users/${this.authData.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid}/`);
  }
```

I tried to type some method like `userRef.child('Messages')`, `userReflistChild('Messages')`, but I got an error that the last method doesn't exist.

I need to avoid the subscribe method, I can solved by using the map method but I'm looking fore new method and the firebase best practices.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the subscribe method. for the program complexity.

Comment: If you are avoiding subscribe then what method do you use to retrieve the data (once for example)?

Comment: Yes  **once** for example. I'm looking for method like child hasChildren(). I don't think that angularfire2 support this methods. so maybe i'll user the FireBase lib.

Comment: what happens if you call (`/Users/${this.authData.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid}/Messages`) and it doesn't exist? if it returns null or undefined you can use that to verify the existence of the node

Comment: Thank you for this solution but isn't the best practices.

Comment: I believe it depends on you use case and that there is no best practice for such a specific case, but of course it is relative to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at AngularFire2 but with the FireBase Real-Time database documentation you can use the "hasChild()" method, described here.

[Firebase Documentation, Datasnapshot, hasChild](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#hasChild)

Comment: I didn't found this hasChild in the angularfire2 doc so i used the FireBased database doc. Thank you

Comment: If you feel that my question is clear please vote for it.